# Extracting values from nested list/tuple/dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

Here's a list that was originally a dictionary that was converted due to sorting;

```
list1 = [ 
            ('key1', {'count': 10, 'value1': Counter({'set1': 5, 'set2': 4, 'set3': 1})}), 
            ('key2', {'count': 8, 'value2': Counter({'set1': 6, 'set2': 2})}),
            ('key3', {'count': 7, 'value3': Counter({'set1': 5, 'set2': 2, 'set3': 1})}) 
        ]
```

What I'm trying get is the first two 'key' objects (along with its count) , and the first 'value' object (along with its count) of each key. For example I'm trying to get a print output of;

```
key1 10
set1 5

key2 8
set1 6
```

Edit: This is what I've already tried (and played around with);

```
for key, value in sorted_x:
    print key, value - only gives key/value as a whole
for key, value in sorted_x:
    print key, value[0] - gives keyerror. I've tried a few variations including nested loops.
for key, value in sorted_x.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

I've tried doing nested loops, along with trying to get parts of the list [1]. But I haven't been able to pin point the data I want and keep getting 'unpack' error messages.

Comment: What is your question? If you want us to help you with your code, you should show us the code you wrote to solve this problem, and how it's not working as intended. Also, the desired output you stated doesn't match your description. What about `value1` and `value2`, for example?

Comment: I edited your output. Did you really want the "key" lines to be separate from the "set" lines? If not, just re-edit the desired output.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker I've edited. I'm still new with python and did try to play around for a while, sorry for my inexperience.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes that your order never changes.

```
def get_stuff(list):
    for i in list[:2]:
        print i[0], i[1].values()[0]
        print i[1].values()[1].keys()[0], i[1].values()[1].values()[0]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. For some reason for `key1`, it shows `set2 4` as opposed to `set1 5`. For the other key (or keys) it shows the first set values fine.